# how to remove unwanted text from retrieving title of a page using python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

Hi All I have written a python program to retrieve the title of a  page it works fine but with some pages, it also receives some unwanted text how to avoid that

here is my program

```
# importing the modules
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# target url
url = 'https://atlasobscura.com'

# making requests instance
reqs = requests.get(url)

# using the BeaitifulSoup module
soup = BeautifulSoup(reqs.text, 'html.parser')

# displaying the title
print("Title of the website is : ")
for title in soup.find_all('title'):
    title_data = title.get_text().lower().strip()
    print(title_data)
```

here is my output

```
atlas obscura - curious and wondrous travel destinations
aoc-full-screen
aoc-heart-solid
aoc-compass
aoc-flipboard
aoc-globe
aoc-pocket
aoc-share
aoc-cancel
aoc-video
aoc-building
aoc-clock
aoc-clipboard
aoc-help
aoc-arrow-right
aoc-arrow-left
aoc-ticket
aoc-place-entry
aoc-facebook
aoc-instagram
aoc-reddit
aoc-rss
aoc-twitter
aoc-accommodation
aoc-activity-level
aoc-add-a-photo
aoc-add-box
aoc-add-shape
aoc-arrow-forward
aoc-been-here
aoc-chat-bubbles
aoc-close
aoc-expand-more
aoc-expand-less
aoc-forum-flag
aoc-group-size
aoc-heart-outline
aoc-heart-solid
aoc-home
aoc-important
aoc-knife-fork
aoc-library-books
aoc-link
aoc-list-circle-bullets
aoc-list
aoc-location-add
aoc-location
aoc-mail
aoc-map
aoc-menu
aoc-more-horizontal
aoc-my-location
aoc-near-me
aoc-notifications-alert
aoc-notifications-mentions
aoc-notifications-muted
aoc-notifications-tracking
aoc-open-in-new
aoc-pencil
aoc-person
aoc-pinned
aoc-plane-takeoff
aoc-plane
aoc-print
aoc-reply
aoc-search
aoc-shuffle
aoc-star
aoc-subject
aoc-trip-style
aoc-unpinned
aoc-send
aoc-phone
aoc-apps
aoc-lock
aoc-verified
```

instead of this I suppose to receive only this line

```
"atlas obscura - curious and wondrous travel destinations"
```

please help me with some idea all other websites are working only some websites gives these problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're finding all the occurences of "title" in the page. Beautiful soup has an attribute `title` specifically for what you're trying to do. Here's your modified code:

```
# importing the modules
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# target url
url = 'https://atlasobscura.com'

# making requests instance
reqs = requests.get(url)

# using the BeaitifulSoup module
soup = BeautifulSoup(reqs.text, 'html.parser')
title_data = soup.title.text.lower()

# displaying the title
print("Title of the website is : ")
print(title_data)
```